# Phonegap/Cordova application name

Tags: cordova

I have a Cordova/Phonegap application written in 6 languages(Italian, French, English...). Is it possible to configure the application in such a way that when someone tries to access the application from a different country, it will show the name (which appears under the icon) in that specific language? For example: if someone from Italy tries to download it, it will show the name in Italian or if someone from France tries to download it, the name will be in French?

Comment: Do you mean 'application name'?

Comment: Yes, the application name which appears in the bottom of the application icon on the device's screen when installed.

Comment: Application names are unique for each applications,To solve above issue create different versions of your application and distribute it according to locations

Comment: This was what I was thinking too but looks like on iOS it is possible to do it natively and I thought that it could be possible in cordova also

Comment: You can detect the system language with `navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage`, but you can't change the application name programmatically after compiling. Instead, consider releasing several localised versions of the app targetting different languages.